# unable to create new service geckodriver; selenium standalone server;

Tags: selenium-ide

I face the same issue as already described with Java, but the answers there dont help me along, I have a selenium Standalone Server.

I am using 
Java version "1.8.0_144" 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
Windows 8.1

11:10:47.836 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.5.3', revision:'a88d25fe6b'

and try to start a selenium standalone server. Startup protocol :

```
C:\Java_External_Jars_e_g_Selenium>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java"
 -jar "C:\Java_External_Jars_e_g_Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar"
11:10:47.836 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe6b
'
11:10:47.837 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-08-31 11:10:47.858:INFO::main: Logging initialized @259ms to org.seleniumhq
.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
11:10:47.912 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
11:10:47.943 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDrive
r registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform
=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN8_1
11:10:47.983 INFO - Using the passthrough mode handler
2017-08-31 11:10:48.009:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2017-08-31 11:10:48.031:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.S
ervletContextHandler@eec5a4a{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for pat
h: /
2017-08-31 11:10:48.036:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletC
ontextHandler@eec5a4a{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-08-31 11:10:48.137:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnecto
r@1f7030a6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-08-31 11:10:48.138:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @539ms
11:10:48.138 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

by starting the Selenium script I have recorded I get an error at the first statement saying go to an URL :

> Server-Error : Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService Build info: version: '3.5.3', revision: 'a88d25fe66', time '2017-08-29T12:54:15.039Z' System info: host: 'PAVILION17' ip: 192.168.178.39', os.name: 'windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: 6.3,java

Answer (score 6):

In your jar command you do not specify the `-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe`. I believe you will need to add this to your java command. It should look something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver="C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe" "C:\Java_External_Jars_e_g_Selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar"
```

This will make sure that your selenium standalone server knows about the gecko driver binary which will be used to launch your Firefox browser. You can download the gecko driver binary from the [mozilla/geckodriver GitHub release page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

Comment: It does NOT work, after used Dwebdriver.gecko.dirver

Comment: This isn't helpful. What is happening? Did the gecko driver flag change? Is this the same problem as the original author?

Comment: keep gecko driver in the same directory as standalone jar. no need to mention the path. It works like that.